# Is it possible to display "Go to" in the right click menu of IE for text in the form of a web address like Chrome/Firefox do?

Tags: internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox, web, hyperlink

For example

[image]

Selecting a non hyperlinked text, chrome and firefox right click dialogs are contextually aware of the kind of text they are selecting. Is it possible to do this in internet explorer ? I'm using the 11 developer preview atm on Windows 8.1.

If I were to write a plugin for this kind of behavior, where would I start ?

Answer (score 1):

Internet Explorer doesn't easily allow you to do exactly this, as it would require running code as the context menu opens, and this is very complicated and not formally supported from the Native Code extension model.

However, you CAN create a non-binary extension (called a Menu Extension) which has this general behavior. About a decade ago, I wrote such an extension called "Linkify and Open" which you can find here: http://www.bayden.com/ietoys/. The source code of the extension is written in HTML and can easily be examined in the IEToys program files folder.

Also, note that in IE you can hit [CTRL+C, CTRL+SHIFT+L] to achieve a similar effect (CTRL+SHIFT+L is the "Go to the URL on the clipboard" shortcut).